# Is there any Spread Spectrum system that uses Rake with cyclic Prefix?

Tags: spread-spectrum

My question is that could the use of cyclic prefix can enhance the performance of Rake receiver ?

I find this proposal here [CP for DSSS Rake Receiver](http://www.wirelesscommunication.nl/reference/chaptr05/cdma/cyclic/cyclic.htm) that seems correct.

**Without CP, ISI emerges and stays as interference in Rake finger.**
[image: without CP, ISI]

**With CP, no ISI.**
[image: with CP, no ISI]

The cost could be an overhead of transmission. But if I take a typical value of delay spread 5µs (ETU channel model) with UMTS SF = 256, the symbol duration is roughly SF/3.84Mcps = 256 / 3.84e6 = 66,66 µs. The cost 5/66.66 = 7.5% is acceptable ?

If the reason is not the overhead cost, is there any reason ? Or Rake receiver performance is not impacted by adding CP thanks to its pilots ?

Answer (score -1):

you can read the following paper, they are using almost the same idea, the title of the paper: Symbol Cyclic Shift Equalization PAM-OFDM - A Low complexity CP-free OFDM Scheme ..  Good luck

Comment: Thanks for anwser. However I do not ask for idea because I am pretty sure this idea works. My doubt relies on its pratical aspect.